# VirtualizingStackPanel with Virtualized List

Tags: wpf, collectionview, virtualizingstackpanel, data-virtualization

I am developing an application that is supposed to display a fairly large amount of items that are loaded from elsewhere (say, a database) in a list/grid-like thing.

As having all the items in memory all the time seems like a waste, I am looking into ways to virtualize a part of my list. [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems just like what I need - however, while it seems to do a good job virtualizing *the UI* of items, I am not sure how to virtualize parts of the underlying item list itself.

As a small sample, consider a WPF application with this as its main window:

```
<Window x:Class="VSPTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="VSPTest" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTpl">
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Margin="2" Padding="4" Background="Chocolate">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="3" Background="Yellow">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border Padding="5">
        <ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTpl}" VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="ListBox_CleanUpVirtualizedItem">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

The code-behind that supplies a list should look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace VSPTest
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private class DataItem
        {
            public DataItem(int index)
            {
                this.index = index;
            }

            private readonly int index;

            public int Index {
                get {
                    return index;
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return index.ToString();
            }
        }

        private class MyTestCollection : IList<DataItem>
        {
            public MyTestCollection(int count)
            {
                this.count = count;
            }

            private readonly int count;

            public DataItem this[int index] {
                get {
                    var result = new DataItem(index);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ADD " + result.ToString());
                    return result;
                }
                set {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public int Count {
                get {
                    return count;
                }
            }

            public bool IsReadOnly {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public int IndexOf(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Insert(int index, Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void RemoveAt(int index)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Add(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Clear()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool Contains(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void CopyTo(Window1.DataItem[] array, int arrayIndex)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool Remove(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public IEnumerator<Window1.DataItem> GetEnumerator()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    yield return this[i];
                }
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MyTestCollection(10000);
        }

        void ListBox_CleanUpVirtualizedItem(object sender, CleanUpVirtualizedItemEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DEL " + e.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

So, this displays an application with a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is forced to virtualize its items with the [`IsVirtualizing` attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It takes its items from the data context, for which a custom [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation is supplied that creates 10000 data items on the fly (when they are retrieved via the indexer).

For debugging purposes, the text `ADD #` (where `#` equals the item index) is output whenever an item is created, and the [`CleanUpVirtualizedItem` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.cleanupvirtualizeditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to output `DEL #` when an item goes out of view and its UI is released by the virtualizing stack panel.

Now, my *wish* is that my custom list implementation supplies items upon request - in this minimal sample, by creating them on the fly, and in the real project by loading them from the database. Unfortunately, `VirtualizingStackPanel` does not seem to behave this way - instead, it invokes the enumerator of the list upon program start and **first retrieves all 10000 items!**

Thus, my question is: **How can I use VirtualizingStackPanel for actual virtualization of data (as in, not loading all the data) rather than just reducing the number of GUI elements?**

- Is there any way to tell the virtualizing stack panel how many items there are in total and telling it to access them by index as needed, rather than using the enumerator? (Like, for example, the [Delphi Virtual TreeView component](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) works, if I recall correctly.)
- Are there any ingenious ways of capturing the event when an item actually comes into view, so at least I could normally just store a unique key of each item and only load the remaining item data when it is requested? (That would seem like a hacky solution, though, as I would still have to provide the full-length list for no real reason, other than satisfying the WPF API.)
- Is another WPF class more suitable for this kind of virtualization?

---

EDIT: Following [dev hedgehog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2800473/dev-hedgehog)'s advice, I have created a custom [`ICollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) implementation. Some of its methods are still implemented to throw `NotImplementedException`s, but the ones that get called when the window is opened do not.

However, it seems that about the first thing that is called for that collection view is the `GetEnumerator` method, enumerating all 10000 elements again (as evidenced by the debug output, where I print a message for every 1000th item), which is what I was trying to avoid.

Here is an example to reproduce the issue:

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionViewTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CollectionViewTest" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
    <Border Padding="5">
        <ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Margin="2" Padding="4" Background="Chocolate">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="3" Background="Yellow">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace CollectionViewTest
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private class DataItem
        {
            public DataItem(int index)
            {
                this.index = index;
            }

            private readonly int index;

            public int Index {
                get {
                    return index;
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return index.ToString();
            }
        }

        private class MyTestCollection : IList<DataItem>
        {
            public MyTestCollection(int count)
            {
                this.count = count;
            }

            private readonly int count;

            public DataItem this[int index] {
                get {
                    var result = new DataItem(index);
                    if (index % 1000 == 0) {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ADD " + result.ToString());
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                set {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public int Count {
                get {
                    return count;
                }
            }

            public bool IsReadOnly {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public int IndexOf(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Insert(int index, Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void RemoveAt(int index)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Add(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Clear()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool Contains(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void CopyTo(Window1.DataItem[] array, int arrayIndex)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool Remove(Window1.DataItem item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public IEnumerator<Window1.DataItem> GetEnumerator()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    yield return this[i];
                }
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }

        private class MyCollectionView : ICollectionView
        {
            public MyCollectionView(int count)
            {
                this.list = new MyTestCollection(count);
            }

            private readonly MyTestCollection list;

            public event CurrentChangingEventHandler CurrentChanging;

            public event EventHandler CurrentChanged;

            public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

            public System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
                get {
                    return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                }
                set {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public IEnumerable SourceCollection {
                get {
                    return list;
                }
            }

            public Predicate<object> Filter {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
                set {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public bool CanFilter {
                get {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public SortDescriptionCollection SortDescriptions {
                get {
                    return new SortDescriptionCollection();
                }
            }

            public bool CanSort {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public bool CanGroup {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public ObservableCollection<GroupDescription> GroupDescriptions {
                get {
                    return new ObservableCollection<GroupDescription>();
                }
            }

            public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> Groups {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public bool IsEmpty {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public object CurrentItem {
                get {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public int CurrentPosition {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public bool IsCurrentAfterLast {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public bool IsCurrentBeforeFirst {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public bool Contains(object item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Refresh()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            private class DeferRefreshObject : IDisposable
            {
                public void Dispose()
                {
                }
            }

            public IDisposable DeferRefresh()
            {
                return new DeferRefreshObject();
            }

            public bool MoveCurrentToFirst()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool MoveCurrentToLast()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool MoveCurrentToNext()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool MoveCurrentToPrevious()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool MoveCurrentTo(object item)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool MoveCurrentToPosition(int position)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return list.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MyCollectionView(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `VirtualizingStackPanel` has nothing to do with Data Virtualization. You need to implement that yourself on the data level

Comment: @HighCore: I see - so I will have to write my own `ItemsControl`-like UI control?

Comment: When you say fairly large amount.  How large?  Do you want to discard items after they are out of view.  Round trips to the database are expensive.  Running a query multiple times is expensive.  Are you running out of memory?  I don't get moving a load to a database and network to save memory.

Comment: @Blam: Maybe 10000 items, maybe a million, maybe more. Ultimately, it depends on the users' filtering parameters. What *can* be said for sure, though, is that especially with so many items, only a few dozens will probably ever be in view. Hence, there is absolutely no point in loading all the other items when all the UI basically needs to know is their total number (for scrolling). In particular, I don't see a reason to risk blocking the UI while unnecessarily loading thousands of items, when those items will probably never be displayed (but are just "there" in the perception of the user ...

Comment: ..., as he or she can reach them by simply scrolling down in the list, if he or she tries).

Comment: You cannot assume there is no point to loading the items. That is how a VirtualizingStackPanel works.  They are not their for perception - they are there.  If you don't like the behavior then don't use a VirtualizingStackPanel as that is simply how it works.  I don't get problem you are trying to solve.  I have used it for 1 million items.  If I only want 10,000 at at time then I page in 10,000 at a time.

Comment: @Blam: Ok, I see now. I had assumed a `VirtualizingStackPanel` is useful for data virtualization, as the virtual list controls in other UI toolkits I had worked with, but apparently, it is not, so I'll look for another way.

Comment: @Blam: Creating one million instances of the tiny `DataItem` class shown in my question already takes a small, but perceiveable amount of time. Adding any useful amount of data to those items - say, a `byte` array with 500 elements - increases that amount of time to something still short, but very noticeable - too long to be acceptable for a fluently reacting UI in any case. That is why in such situations, data virtualization usually comes into play, as the UI does not require most of the items themselves, just an idea of the overall number, so only a small part of the data needs to be loaded.

Comment: VirtualizingStackPanel is what it is.  It loads the data.  You can argue it does not need to load the data but that is not going to change the behavior.  It is UI virtualiztion only.  If you want different behavior then you will need to use another control.

Answer (score 4):

You want `Data Virtualization`, you have `UI Virtualization` right now.

You can take a look more about data virtualization [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

Answer (score 3):

To get around the issue where the `VirtualizingStackPanel` attempts to enumerate over its entire data source, I stepped through the source code on http://referencesource.microsoft.com (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/VirtualizingStackPanel.cs)

I'll provide the TLDR here:

- If you specified `VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"` you need to make sure all the items displayed/virtualized from its `ItemTemplate` are the same size (height). Even if you are a pixel different, all bets are off and you'll most likely trigger a loading of the whole list.
- If the items being displayed are not **exactly** the same height, you must specify `VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"`.

My Findings:

There are several 'landmines' in the `VirtualizingStackPanel` source that trigger an attempt to iterate over the entire collection via the index operator `[]`. One of these is during the Measurement cycle of which it attempts to update the virtualized container size to make the scrollviewer accurate. If any new items being added during this cycle aren't the same size when in `Pixel` mode, it iterates over the whole list to adjust and you are hosed.

Another 'landmine' has something to do with selection and triggering a hard refresh. This is applicable more for grids - but under the hood, its using a `DataGridRowPresenter` which derives from `VirtualizingStackPanel`. Because it wants to keep selections in sync between refreshing, it attempts to enumerate all. This means we need to disable selection (keep in mind that clicking a row triggers a selection).

I solved this by deriving my own grid and overriding `OnSelectionChanged`:

```
protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        UnselectAll();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

There seems to be other gotchas, but I haven't been able to reliably trigger them yet. The real 'fix' would be to roll our own `VirtualizingStackPanel` with looser constraints for generating the containersize. After all, for large datasets (million+), the accuracy of scrollbar matters much less. If I have time to do this, I'll update my answer with the gist/github repo.

In my tests I used a data virtualization solution available here: https://github.com/anagram4wander/VirtualizingObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there just it is not the VirtualizingStackPanel that invokes the enumerator of the list.

When you Binding to ListBox.ItemsSource there will be a ICollectionView interface created automatically between your actual Source of data and ListBox Target. That interface is the meany invoking the enumerator.

How to fix this? Well just write your own CollectionView class that inherits from ICollectionView interface. Pass it to ItemsSource and ListBox will know you wish to have your own view of data. Which is what you sort of need. Then once ListBox realizes you are using your own view, just return the needed data when requested by ListBox. That would be it. Play nice with ICollectionView :)

Comment: That sounds like a promising approach, however, after implementing a minimal version of `ICollectionView` (i.e. adding method implementations until no `NotImplementedException`s are thrown any more), the `GetEnumerator` method of the `ICollectionView` implementation gets called, *still* enumerating all 10000 items. Also, looking at [`ICollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I cannot see any members that would allow to retrieve any specific items, or their total number.

Comment: So, it seems like even with `ICollectionView`, any items displays just *have to* enumerate the full list.

Comment: I cant really say without code. However I did it with ICollectionView interface when I had to write data virtualization for TreeView. It should work. Check it again or post us the code you are using. Upload the project somewhere online

Comment: I have edited my question with an example that uses a collection view. `GetEnumerator` is called and all 10000 items are retrieved right upon launching the application, rather than gradually, as they come into view.

Answer (score 1):

Long time after the question was posted, but may be useful to someone out there. While solving the exact same problem, I found out that your `ItemsProvider` (in your case, `MyTestCollection`,) has to implement `IList` interface (non-templated). Only then the `VirtualizingStackPanel` accesses the individual items via `[]` operator, rather than enumerating them via `GetEnumerator`. In your case, it should be enough to add:

```
    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get { return this[index]; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public int IndexOf(DataItem item)
    {
        // TODO: Find a good way to find out the item's index
        return DataItem.Index;
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        var item = value as DataItem;
        if (item != null)
            return IndexOf(item);
        else
            throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
```

All the remaining `IList`'s members can be left unimplemented, as far as I can see.